# If $b_n =o(1/n)$, construct a convergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $b_n=o(a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A problem from Zorich's *Analysis*:

> If $b_n=o(1/n)$, show that one can construct a convergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $b_n=o(a_n)$ as $n \to \infty$.

I've come up with some possible series, but can't fully prove it.

If we use $a_n=1/n$, the second condition is satisfied but not the first, so I guess I need something "smaller" than $1/n$ but "bigger" than $b_n$. My first attempts were the arithmetic or geometric mean of $b_n$ and $1/n$, but I couldn't prove their convergence nor come up with a counterexample.

Then I thought about Leibniz's criterion, and tried to set:
$$a_n=b_n-b_{n-1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
which, according to Cauchy criterion, seem to converge. I'm not sure how to prove $b_n=o(a_n)$ though.

So, I wonder what the solution is. Also, are there any counterexamples to the previous series, that is, does the series $\sum \sqrt{|b_n|/n}$ converge?

Comment: In Zorich's convention, does writing "$b_n = o(a_n)$" imply $a_n > 0$? If not, this is trivial by taking an alternating series. If it does, the convergence of $\sum b_n$ must be demanded.

Comment: No, it's not. Oh well, a simple alternating series is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use $ a_n = (-1)^{n+1} / n $.  The series is well known to converge (with limit $1/2$).

That $b_n = o(1/n) $ as $n \to \infty $ means $|n b_n| \to 0 $. Then

$$\begin{align} \left| \frac{b_n}{a_n} \right| &= nb_n \to 0 \quad\text{as }n\to\infty
\end{align}$$

so that $b_n = o(a_n) $.

I hope this helps.

---

Postscript:  I had wondered whether $a_n$ could be found with all positive terms.  I think not.  If $b_n = 1/(n\log n)$, say for $n > 2$ then $b_n =o(1/n)$.  However, an integral test shows that $ \sum_n b_n $ diverges, and therefore any positive series $a_n$ with $b_n =o(a_n)$ must also have divergent sum.  This is not a rigorous proof but hopefully forms the basis of one.